# Drupal: How to wrap inline images into additional markup

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

i need to wrap images into additional markup for further css styling. I would like to have something like that: `<p><span><img src="path/to/image" alt="alt"/></span></p>`.

The images are added directly on the specific node using following modules:

1. http://drupal.org/project/insert
2. http://drupal.org/project/image
3. http://drupal.org/project/cck -> ImageField

Here is the content of my node-[type].tpl.php:

```
<div id="article">
    <div id="article-header">
        <h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
        <?php if ($submitted): ?>
            <p class="created"><?php echo date("d. F Y - H:i", $created).t(' von ').$name; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="article-body">
        <?php print $content; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($links): ?>
        <div class="extra-links">
            <?php print $links; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if($node->comment == 0 && isset($node->comment_count) && $node->comment_count < 1): ?>
    <div id="comments">
        <p class="note">Kommentare geschlossen</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think i have to do something with `$content`. But i really have no idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the insert module then there is an option to add "Additional CSS classes" to the image in the settings for insert in the imagefield.

This will add a class to `<img>` (but it will not wrap a span around `<img>` like you want). Using this class you can do custom css you want.

This approach has some caveats

1. You will need to use the WYSIWYG filter module (http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) to prevent classes from being stripped out from the img tag (or you will need to use the full html format which is obviously not a good idea if non administrators are entering content on the site)
2. You need to allow the class attribute for the  tag in the WYSIWYG settings. However under advanced options make sure you allow the classes that are allowed.
3. You should disable the HTML Filter as you are now using the WYSIWYG filter

so your rule for  tag will look something like
img[!src|title|alt|class]. Make sure the class you want e.g. custom-css-class is whitelisted under the advanced rules section for WYSIWYG

**Edit:** Ok I understand your requirement better now.

1. For imagefields that are NOT inline
   (i.e. in content areas) you can
   override the content-field.tpl.php
   by renaming it to
   content-field-[FIELD_NAME].tpl.php 
   You can wrap the imagefield with
   whatever tags you want in this file.
   Please see
   http://www.advantagelabs.com/drupal-colonoscopy-or-how-theme-cck-field-drupal-6
2. For images that are inline and you still want to add some wrapping
   HTML you can use
   http://drupal.org/project/customfilter
   This is an awesome module (tricky to
   use but it works!!). You can search
   for the  tag and add arbitrary
   stuff around it. See
   http://drupal.org/node/210551 for
   documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what i need to do. I can select my image simply with `#article img {}` in my css file and do some solid css styling on it. But i need additional markup to solve my layout problem. You should probably know that i need to use multiple css background images. Css 3 and Javascript (jQuery) are not an option.

Comment: You can override content-field.tpl.php for imagefields and use custom filter (see edited answer above)

Comment: NoParrots, the custom filter module is a great suggestion but to comlicated for me :) I found a other way. http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imageupload Added custom HTML by default. I changed the module for my concerns and it works well now. Thank again very much :)